# Does the MCKP problem have faster implementation with pulp?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have a MCKP problem with lots of constraints, and I solve it with pulp as follow python code

```
def func(N,M,V,T):
    t0 = time.time()
    # Problem Definition
    prob = pulp.LpProblem("MCKP", pulp.LpMaximize)

    # Define the X needed to be solved ---- which has N customers, M products
    X = [[pulp.LpVariable(f"X_{i}_{j}", lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
        for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

    # Define the optimization object ---- maximize the total Value
    obj = pulp.LpAffineExpression()
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            obj += X[i][j] * V[i][j]
    prob += obj

    # Define the constraints 
    for i in range(N):
        prob += pulp.lpSum(X[i]) == 1   #Each customer must select 1 product
    for i in range(M):
        prob += pulp.lpSum([X[k][i] for k in range(N)]) == T[i]  #Each product must be selected by certain number of customers

    prob.solve()
    t1 = time.time()
    print("Used: {}".format(int(t1 - t0)))

N=10000 #N customers
M=12    #M products
V=np.random.random((N,M))  #Products's value to customers
T=[800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 1200]  #Constraints
func(N,M,V,T)
```

This code takes over 30 seconds while N=10000 and M=12, is there any optimization suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added the example test code. Hope for your answer!

Comment: Can you explain more why you need a constraint for every single customer? It will be difficult to make this fast at its current size.

Comment: I find the step of T constraint cost most time, and this constraint is because of the stock is fixed. (At fact, without T constraint, the answer is very simple, which is each people select the largest V's corresponding product.)

Comment: Why is the T constraint an equality? Wouldn't it make more sense to say _at most_ T products should be purchased from available stock?

Comment: Understand this as a allocation problem, the things to be allocated is limited and fixed. (Here I use the words `product` and `customer`, just for simple example). The problem can exist in real life, and I am looking for more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, "no". For a big problem like this, there isn't any simple way to make solution shorter.

There are some issues with the way that you perform PuLP problem setup, and also scipy problem setup is much, much faster; but the actual solution time is fairly close.

```py
import time
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np
import pulp
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse as sp


def solve_pulp(M: int, N: int, V: np.ndarray, T: Sequence[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    :param M: Number of products
    :param N: Number of customers
    :param V: Product value for each customer (M, N)
    :param T: Product assignment counts
    :return X: Customer-product assignments (M, N)
    """

    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    print('Setting up problem...', end=' ')

    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='MCKP', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)

    # Assignments per customer and product
    X = [
        pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name=f'X_{i}', indices=range(N),  # over j
            cat=pulp.LpBinary,
        )
        for i in range(M)
    ]

    # Define the optimization object - maximize the total Value
    prob.objective = pulp.lpDot(X, V)

    for j in range(N):
        prob += pulp.lpSum([
            X[i][j] for i in range(M)
        ]) == 1  # Each customer must select 1 product

    for i in range(M):
        # Each product must be selected by certain number of customers
        prob += pulp.lpSum(X[i]) == T[i]

    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'{t1 - t0:.1f} s')
    print('Solving...')

    prob.solve()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Solution time: {t2 - t1:.1f} s')

    return (
        np.array([
            [elm.value() for elm in row]
            for row in X
        ]) > 0.5
    ).astype(np.uint8)
'''
Setting up problem... 3.8 s
Time (CPU seconds):             75.27
Time (Wallclock seconds):       75.27

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       76.66   (Wallclock seconds):       76.66

Solution time: 86.1 s
'''


def solve_scipy(M: int, N: int, V: np.ndarray, T: Sequence[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    :param M: Number of products
    :param N: Number of customers
    :param V: Product value for each customer (M, N)
    :param T: Product assignment counts
    :return X: Customer-product assignments (M, N)
    """

    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    print('Setting up problem...', end=' ')

    c = -V.ravel()
    integrality = np.ones(shape=M*N, dtype=np.uint8)
    bounds = Bounds(lb=0, ub=1)

    customer_excl = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack(
            blocks=(sp.eye(N),) * M,
            format='csc',
        ),
        lb=np.ones(N),
        ub=np.ones(N),
    )

    product_assign = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.kron(  # kronecker
            A=sp.eye(M),
            B=np.ones((1, N)),
            format='csc',
        ),
        lb=T,
        ub=T,
    )

    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'{t1 - t0:.1f} s')
    print('Solving...')

    result = milp(
        c=c,
        integrality=integrality,
        bounds=bounds,
        constraints=(customer_excl, product_assign),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Solution time: {t2 - t1:.1f} s')
    return result.x.astype(np.uint8).reshape((M, N))
'''
Setting up problem... 0.0 s
Solution time: 77.4 s
'''


def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

    M = 12      # products
    N = 10_000  # customers
    # N = 23
    V = rand.random(size=(M, N))
    T = (800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 1200)
    # T = (1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1)

    solve_pulp(M, N, V, T)
    solve_scipy(M, N, V, T)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice side-by-side!

Comment: Thanks! In a couple of hours I'd like to add an approximative partitioning approach but I don't know how much it will help.